# Is it possible to have $P(\mu_X -2\sigma_X < X < \mu_X + 2\sigma_X)=0.6$?

Tags: distributions, self-study

> Suppose $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu_X$ and standard deviation $\sigma_X$. Is it possible to have $P(\mu_X -2\sigma_X < X < \mu_X + 2\sigma_X)=0.6$? If yes, give an example. If no, explain why.

My thoughts:

Would I use Chebyshev's inequality to solve this? This question follows a chapter discussing distributions, but I feel like this is an easy application of the Chebyshev Inequality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guide:

$$P(|X - \mu_X|<2\sigma_X)=0.6$$

$$1-P(|X - \mu_X|<2\sigma_X)=0.4$$

$$P(|X - \mu_X|\ge 2\sigma_X)=0.4$$

Now recall that Chebyshev's inequality says that

$$P(|X - \mu_X|\ge k\sigma_X)\le \frac1{k^2}$$

Identify the $k$ and that should answer the question.

Comment: So, $P(|X-\mu_X| \ge k\sigma_X) \le 0.25$, which means this is not possible, correct? I figured that the solution would utilize Chebyshev's Inequality. Thank you.

Comment: I suppose the trickiest part is learning how to manipulate those inequalities.

Comment: yup, it is correct.